# TableRow dynamically created with different contents

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

I am creating `TableRows` dynamically. And there are two types of content for these `TableRows`.
Some have 4 Views.
And some have 2 Views.

The problem is that `TableRows` with two, try to occupy the same space as the layout of which have four.
This is happening:

Img ThisTextViewHasThisSize

Img TV0 ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**_TV1 TV2

...

```
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

        ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
        tr.addView(button);

        TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
        tv0.setText(array[i].something0());

            if (another type of TableRow) {
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setText(array[i].something1());
            tv2.setText(array[i].something2());
            tr.addView(tv1);
            tr.addView(tv2);

        }
        tr.addView(tv0);

        tl.addView(tr);
    }
```

Someone can tell me how to let the TableRows layouts totally independent from each other?

Comment: Are you sure that a `ListView` is not better suited for your purposes?

Comment: Oh, I really dont know. I need do put a background image for each "cell". Is it possible? Im gonna studying about.

Comment: but the question still remains ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the span of a view within the table by using `TableRow.LayoutParams`. Eg:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

//all rows have this button
ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
tr.addView(button);

TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
tv0.setText("hey");

if (some condition == true) {
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("heay 2");
    tv2.setText("hey 3");
    tr.addView(tv0);
    tr.addView(tv1);
    tr.addView(tv2);
}else {
    TableRow.LayoutParams trlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    trlp.span = 3;
    tv.setLayoutParams(trlp);
    tr.addView(tv0);
}
```

Comment: If this worked for you, then you should mark this as the "Accepted" answer.(or you could upvote it) :-)